# Swift - Extra argument 'transition' in call

Tags: ios7, swift, ios8, sprite-kit

```
self.view?.presentScene(GameOverScene(), transition: transition)
```

apparently : "Extra argument 'transition' in call" is the error.
and since this is my first app I don't know how to solve it.

similar errors are:

```
self.view?.presentScene(scene, transition: true)
```

with the same error message. If that could be solved, it would be my first working app.

It is written on swift(Xcode) and spritekit.

Thanks for the answer in advance.

ps:

```
self.runAction(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.waitForDuration(3.0),
            SKAction.runBlock({
                var transition:SKTransition = SKTransition.flipHorizontalWithDuration(0.5)
                var scene:SKScene = GameScene(size: self.size)
                self.view?.presentScene(scene, transition: true)
```

this is the paragraph for the second error.

Comment: What is type is `self` here?

Comment: probably because the `transition` parameter is not a boolean...

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to pass in an actual instance of SKTransition?

```
self.view?.presentScene(GameOverScene(), transition: SKTransition.crossFadeWithDuration(20))
```

You can find an overview about the different transitions over here: https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKTransition_Ref/index.html